# Variable always equaling 0 despite scanner assigning different number

Tags: java

For whatever reason, my variable 'hours' is only existing as 0. When I enter 96 as distance, 1 as hours, and 43 as minutes, my answer is 133.9 mph. It SHOULD be 55.9223. I apologize for asking what I'm sure is an obvious question, but I'm very early in learning java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class mph
{
private double distance, hours, minutes;
private double mph;

public mph()
{
    setNums(0,0,0);
    mph=0.0;
}

public mph(double dist, double hrs, double mins)
{

    distance=dist;
    hours=hours;
    minutes=mins;
}

public void setNums(double dist, double hrs, double mins)
{
    dist=distance;
    hrs=hours;
    mins=minutes;



}

public void calcMPH()
{
    hours=minutes/60; //hours is not being input, it counts as zero regardless of what's entered
    mph=distance/hours;

}

public void print()
{
     System.out.print((int)distance+" miles in "+(int)hours+" hours and "+(int)minutes+" minutes = "+mph+" mph.\n");

}
```

}

-------------------separate file----------------

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class mphRunner
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);

    out.print("Enter the distance :: ");
    double dist = keyboard.nextInt();

    out.print("Enter the hours :: ");
    double hrs = keyboard.nextInt();

    out.print("Enter the minutes :: ");
    double mins = keyboard.nextInt();

    mph test = new mph(dist, hrs, mins);
    test.calcMPH();
    test.print();

}
}
```

I apologize if I messed up the proper formatting somehow, this is my first post on the site. 
Edit: Oh my god I'm a moron.

Comment: you should always prefix instance variable references with the keyword `this` and you will not have simple typos like this be invisible. There is so much wrong with this it is hard to know where to start other than a **basic introductory to Java tutorial**.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your variable `hours` to itself instead of to the parameter `hrs`.  Change

```
hours=hours;
```

to

```
hours=hrs;
```

Comment: `this.hours = hrs;` would be the best advice

Answer (score 0):

#### This is what an idiomatic version of your attempt would look like:

#### [Q33636764.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q33636764.java)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q33636764
{
    private static int getData(final Scanner scanner, final String message)
    {
        System.out.print(message);
        if (scanner.hasNextInt()) { return scanner.nextInt(); }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter an Integer!");
            return getData(scanner, message);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        final int dist = getData(keyboard, "Enter the distance : ");
        final int hrs = getData(keyboard, "Enter the hours : ");
        final int mins = getData(keyboard, "Enter the minutes : ");

        final Mph mph = new Mph(dist, hrs, mins);
        System.out.format("%d miles in %d hours and %d minutes %.2f mph.", dist, hrs, mins, mph.calculate());
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static class Mph
    {
        private final double distance;
        private final double hours;
        private final double minutes;

        public Mph(final double distance, final double hours, final double minutes)
        {
            this.distance = distance;
            this.hours = hours;
            this.minutes = minutes;
        }

        public double calculate()
        {
            return this.distance / this.hours + this.minutes / 60;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Outputs:

```
Enter the distance : 100
Enter the hours : 1
Enter the minutes : 0
100 miles in 1 hours and 0 minutes 100.00 mph.
```